# CakePHP - BaseAuthenticate altering loginRedirect

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have a number of authentication components that extend the `BaseAuthenticate` class. These are setup in the AppController in the normal way.

**Is it possible for an authentication component to alter the AuthComponent's loginRedirect variable?**

To clarify the situation, one of my authentication components looks at a certain subset of users. It checks to see if the credentials are valid before checking to see if that person has any outstanding invoices.  Depending on the outstanding value, I'd like to redirect the user to a given page or block them out altogether.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to @jerermyharris for pushing me in the right direction. Here goes with what I ended up doing.

**1. Extended the AuthComponent**

```
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

    class MyAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {

      var $components = array('Session'); 

      public function identify(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        if (empty($this->_authenticateObjects)) {
            $this->constructAuthenticate();
        }
        foreach ($this->_authenticateObjects as $auth) {
            $result = $auth->authenticate($request, $response);
            if (!empty($result) && is_array($result)) {
                if(isset($result['Redirect']))
                {
                    $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $result['Redirect']);            
                }
                return $result;
            }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**2. Add this the AppController components**

```
public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'className' => 'MyAuth',
        )
);
```

Add this bit around whatever other definitions you have for your AuthComponent.

**3. Return a redirect from your authentication component**

```
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class TutorAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        $user = ...... // However you authenticate your user
        $user['Redirect'] = "http://example.com";
        return $user;
    }
}
```

So now if you want to redirect based on the user you can just add it in, if you don't then cake will obey the directives you set up in AppController.

Wow, that seems like I've had to do loads extra, but it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. The AuthComponent's redirect location is just a session variable (so technically it can be set anywhere).

To change the redirect location, you can set it manually:

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', 'http://example.com');
```

On the next request, they will be redirected by the AuthComponent.

Or, have your component redirect them then and there:

```
$this->_Collection->getController()->redirect('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremey, I ended up going down this route. It's worth noting that the BaseAuthenticate classes don't have access to the Auth component by default and I had to do `App::import('Component', 'Sesssion')->write('Auth.redirect', 'http://example.com');`

Comment: Yes. That's because authentication classes should only *authenticate*. They shouldn't redirect. Redirect logic belongs in a component or the controller. Components and controllers can have other components (like `Session`).

Comment: That's an interesting point, but if not there, where should it go? This bit of logic is specific to this subset of users, they already have their own authentication component do you think that they should also have their own controller to handle this type of logic?

Comment: Hmm, well without knowing your exact problem I'd say extend the AuthComponent, override the [`_getUser()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/auth-component#l-580) method (which is what iterates through the authentication objects) and handle setting it there. Each authentication object could hold a redirect location, and `_getUser()` would set it there.

Comment: So having now extended the `AuthComponent` with `MyAuthComponent`, do I have to access it via `$this->MyAuth` everywhere or is there some way of aliasing this back to `$this->Auth`?

Comment: Nope! You can "alias" your component to be read as `$this->Auth`. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#loading-and-unloading-objects

Comment: Wow, I'm learing a lot here.  So where would you put the `$this->Components->load()` declaration then? Inside `Appcontroller::beforeFilter()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18235/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-rob-forrest)

Comment: Long old chat there Jeremy, you've been a great help.

Comment: Oh duh Jeremy. Totally scanned the code wrong. My bad, but glad you got it all up and running.